# Selecting an Asp.net control using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a slight issue where I can't seem to select a User Control ID using jquery. The User Control is a message panel which appears when an action happens. So when the page loads this message panel isn't part of the page. It is only when the user interacts with the page i.e. add an image that the message panel shows with a message.

**Page controls**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pan_cntrls" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewImg" runat="server" Text="Add new image" OnClick="btnAddNewImg_Click"
       Visible="true" />
   <uc9:MessagePanel ID="messagepanel1" runat="server"></uc9:MessagePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PageContent_IMG1_messagepanel1_divMessageBox").click(function () {
            alert("handler called");
        });
   });
```

**What firebug shows**

```
<div class="errorBox confirmation" id="PageContent_IMG1_messagepanel1_divMessageBox" style="height: 50px;">
```

I can select other IDs using jquery but not this one. I should also point out that I am using a modalpopupextender on the page. So when I submit data the page is doing postback. I tried using delegate because the ID is added to the DOM after page load but its not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is it as simple as the `##` at the beginning of the jquery selector? - should it just be a single `#`?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo where I pasted the code.

Comment: Something else is wrong. You code is fine, check http://jsfiddle.net/nsgmx/

Comment: Do you have asp.net ajax modalpopupextender ? How you postback the data? Show the relevant markup/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that you're adding the handler at `$(document).ready`. The divs don't exist yet, so this call does nothing.

You need to attach the click handler after the div hits the page. There are a couple of ways you can achieve this:

**1**

Use `add_endRequest`, so execute the `document.ready` code after async queries:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
    $("#PageContent_IMG1_messagepanel1_divMessageBox").click(function () {
        alert("handler called");
    });
});
```

**or 2**

Explicitly make an addHandler function and cause it using an injection from asp.net:

In JS:

```
function addHandler (ctrlID) {
    $("#" + ctrlID).click(function () {
        alert("handler called");
    });
};
```

In ASP.Net:

Use `RegisterStartupScript` to call the addHandler, passing the `ClientID` of the control that needs the handler adding. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) for info on RegisterStartupScript.

The first of these options is less efficient than the second (as it will execute after all postbacks), but easier to implement.

Comment: I've not done it here, but you should use the `<%=divMessageBox.ClientID%>` instead of hardcoding the full clientID, as it will possible change as you work on other elements in the page.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I knew that the jquery couldn't see the div but wasn't sure about how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=PageContent_IMG1_messagepanel1_divMessageBox.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            alert("handler called");
        });
   });
```

this way, you gonna be sure that it's the id on the client side

When ASP.NET renders server side controls it gives them unique client ids which are different from their server ids and if you are not sure, you can check the source of your ASP.NET page

Comment: Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'PageContent_IMG1_messagepanel1_divMessageBox' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Its not part of the page when page first loads.

Answer (score 0):

To get user-control's ID at client-side, you have to set its ClientID property.